# HTML fields json encoded as deep nested objects

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, gson

I have some Java REST ws handling POST data from a simple HTML form.
I want to make the client code send to the ws the right JSON to make the server code populate my objects the right way.

I have the following data structure:

```
public class CarDTO
{
    String id;
    String defaultName;
    List<CarCategoryDTO> carCategoryDTOs;
    List<CarTranslationsDTO> carTranslationsDTOs;
    /* getter, setter, constructors*/
}

public class CarCategoryDTO
{
    String id;
    String defaultName;
    /* getter, setter, constructors*/
}

public class CarTranslationsDTO
{
    int id;
    String name;
    LanguageDTO languageDTO;
    /* getter, setter, constructors*/
}


public class LanguageDTO
{
    String code;
    /* getter, setter, constructors*/
}
```

POST Action:

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
public Response saveCar(String args)
{
    try 
    {
        Gson g  = new GsonBuilder().create();
        CarDTO carDTO = g.fromJson(args, CarDTO.class);

        System.out.println(carDTO);

        return  Response.ok(g.toJson(carDTO)).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
<form   id="form_car"
        enctype="application/json"
        action="http://www.someurl.com:8080/rest/0.1/car/save"
        method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="defaultName" />
    <input type="hidden" name="carTranslationsDTOs[0][languageDTO][code]" value='en'>
    <input type="text" name="carTranslationsDTOs[0][name]">
    <input type="text" name="carCategoryDTOs[0][defaultName]" value="cat1">
    <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Salva"/>
</form>
<script>
    jQuery("#submitbutton").click(function(){
        var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery("#form_car").serializeObject());
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://www.someurl.com:8080/rest/0.1/car/save",
            type:"POST",
            data:formData,
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also added the following jQuery extension, but it wasn't enough: [jquery.serializeObject.js](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject)

The problem is the mapping with Collection of parameters, the result is that I can populate only CarDTO.id and CarDTO.defaultName.
How can I make it work?

**EDIT 25/03/2015:**

I figured up that the simplest way to solve my problem is to make the json manually from javascript at the submit, tough this don't satisfy me because a lot of the logic is client side, and exposing all my DTO structures in this way is awful.
I didn't know of any custom deserialization in Gson, I think that's the right path to follow.

Any other help and different opinions are well accepted.

Comment: can you provide formdata?

Comment: it's already there, HTML + Javascript

Comment: i am saying output of stringify statement. so that can relate it with class mapping.

Comment: You have a lot of libraries to serialize a form to JSON in your desired way, take a look at https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON, https://github.com/tborychowski/formparams etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to process the JSON until it's in a form that Gson can recognize, i.e. something along the lines of:

```js
{
  "defaultName": "Ford",
  "carCategoryDTOs": [{
    "defaultName": "cat1"
  }],
  "carTranslationsDTOs": [{
    "name": "Ford",
    "languageDTO": {
      "code": "en"
    }
  }]
}
```

If you still run into issues, you may need to write a custom deserializer, see the [Writing a Deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer) section of the Gson User Guide.

Note that you're naming conventions for your `carTranslationsDTOs` is off. Since it's already a `has_many` relationship, and each `carTranslationsDTOs` is actually a single translation, this should be named `carTranslationDTOs` according to your convention.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't map to your data structure; the following is the result JSON using your code:

```
{
 "defaultName":"default car name",
 "carTranslationsDTOs[0][languageDTO][code]":"en",
 "carTranslationsDTOs[0][name]":"car name in en",
 "carCategoryDTOs[0][defaultName]":"cat1"
}
```

While GSON expects something like

```
{
 "defaultName":"default car name",
 "carCategoryDTOs":[{"defaultName":"cat1"}],
 "carTranslationsDTOs":[{"name":"car name in en",languageDTO:{"code":"en"}}],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery plugin that serializes/deserializes flat and nested html form data to / from javascript / json. I haven't tried in your particular case but as far as I can see it might solve the problem.

Just have a look at https://github.com/omanshardt/jquery-uicForm3.git.